# How to loop selected pages in PowerShell model Treelist

Tags: powershell

I am using Sitecore Powershell Module, to select list of pages that can be later on translated and created new item.

I am using this block of code

```
@{
        Name = "listOfPages"
        Title = "Select pages you wish to copy on other languages"
        Editor = "Treelist"
        Source = "DataSource=/sitecore/content/XXXX/Home&DatabaseName=master"
        Tooltip = "Select one or more page from list."
    },
```

Comment: If you have any conditions for filtering then you can use the Get-ChildItem commandlet to get all the items and filter them using Where-Object commandlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result of all the selected pages in `TreeList`, you need to write your code something like this.

```
$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="listOfPages"; Title="Select Language"; Options=$languageTypes; Tooltip="Select one or more page from list"; Editor="Treelist"; Source = "DataSource=/sitecore/content/DC Decorio/DecorioLocal/Home&DatabaseName=master"} 
    )
    Title = "Select pages you wish to copy on other languages"
    Description = "Choose the criteria."
    Width = 550
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true    
}

$result = Read-Variable @props
$listOfPages | Select-Object DisplayName, FullPath
```

This will give you the list of pages in output. You can use the variable `$listOfPages` and create a loop and write your code.

Create a loop like this

```
$listOfPages | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.DisplayName
}
```

Hope this helps.